# iOS: ScrollView Paging too far

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've got a collectionView that I am resizing. After the resize, I swipe to get to the next cell and the paging goes too far. However, when I programmatically `scrollToRow`, the scrollview snaps perfectly.

At first, I thought the constraints may be causing the issue. Now I have a feeling that after I apply the transformation to the `collectionview`, either the `scrollView` or the `flowLayout` isn't registering the change in size.

Is there a better way to resize a collectionView or a way to register the transformation with the scrollView?

Resize Code:

```
self.slideCollectionViewTopConstraint.constant = 80
self.slideCollectionViewLeftConstraint.constant = 150
self.slidesCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.35, y: 1.35)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you update the contraints you should tell the view it needs to recalculate its layout with [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded).  Also can't you just update the width and height constraints instead of using a scale matrix?  Per the documentation the [transform](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) doesn't affect autolayout, just the appearance.

Comment: I do call layoutIfNeeded, to no avail. Same behavior. As for width and height...maybe I'll give that a go. My only worry is the smoothness of the animation